# Algorithm design for Bandwidth Availability

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a graph of N nodes. I have the bandwidth consumption of all the links. A link with least bandwidth available in a path from Node s to Node t is called the bottleneck of the path. To find the bandwidth availability between Node s and Node t, I am running a DFS to find N number of paths between the two nodes and then I am finding bottleneck of each path. I am then taking an average of these bottlenecks to find an average bottleneck. Can I use this as a single number to denote the bandwidth availability between Node s and Node t? What are the pros and cons? Please suggest me a right place to ask if this is not the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is Network Flow Analysis, and particularly [Max flow, Min Cut.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)

Your current implementation ignores the fact that you might be able to send data along multiple paths at once.

One last note - you can use Djikstra's alogirithm to find the path with the highest bottleneck.

Comment: Yes. I want to send data along multiple paths. In that case, Max flow, min cut will solve my problem. But I have multiple source and multiple sinks. I want to know available bandwidth between each pair of source and sink. I want to be fair for all pairs.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting. I'll think about it and let you know if I come up with a way to do that fairly.